# Inconsistent results in solr when query contains special characters

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to solr search on some log files which are already indexed using solrJ. I want to be able to search a string and the result is the name of the files which contain that particular string.
    But if I use special characters the search results are inconsistent. I have admin@10.x.x.x in my log file. If I search admin, I get proper results. If I search admin@ then also I get proper results. But if I search admin@10 then I am getting no results. And if I search some string like *a@ then I get some results which doesn't even have that string.

I tried escaping metacharacters. That did not work.

I cannot show any code because it is related to my office work.

Note: By results I mean names of log files which contain that particular string. (Not that the filename itself contains the string. That particular file(s) contents contain that search string)

Comment: you may need to share whats the field type used for the field...that would be helpful in resolving the issue faster

Comment: This will depend entirely on the field type defined for the field as Abhijit mentions. Create test data and include the necessary configuration that shows the error, otherwise it'll be just guessing. From your description this sounds like something that tokenizes on `@`, but not other special characters (such as `.` will be skipped for tokenization when there's content on both sides because of domain names).

Comment: To elaborate further, you don't need to share your company code (and shouldn't). You need to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the problem. You might even find that you discover the solution by doing so.